# What is the meaning of "the night was out"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, idioms

[**Source**](https://books.google.com/books?id=DSkKgicmR-0C&pg=PA3&lpg=PA3&dq=%22He%20knew%20that%20authorities%20would%20be%20after%20him%20like%20baying%20hounds%20before%20the%20night%20was%20out.%22&source=bl&ots=sJECoLExwC&sig=qoDg3VFG1lcdE0_4TK5D7MG7OCk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjhp43wte3PAhXLyoMKHa7JCL0Q6AEILTAE#v=onepage&q=%22He%20knew%20that%20authorities%20would%20be%20after%20him%20like%20baying%20hounds%20before%20the%20night%20was%20out.%22&f=false)

What is the meaning of "the night was out"?
Context sentence:

> He knew that authorities would be after him like baying hounds before the night was out.

Comment: Before the night was ended - as in *before the day/month/year/season/etc was out*.

Comment: "before morning had broken"

Answer (score 2):

"Before the night is/was out" is an idiomatic expression that means "before night is over" or "before dawn".  It has a somewhat romantic/poetic feel to it, so as with many idioms you should fully understand its nuance so you won't use it in the wrong context.

> Before the night was out, they had stolen several hundred thousand dollars from the biggest banks in the city.
>
> Before the night is out, Santa delivers all his presents to all the good children around the world.
>
> The Blue Ninja swore to get revenge on his master's killer before the night was out.

As a side note, the equivalent to this idiom for daytime is "Before the day is/was done":

> Before the day was done, he planned to sample every food truck downtown.